# Python string/float comparison

Tags: python

I've run into the following issue, with my code below. Basically I have a list of objects with an id and a corresponding weight, and I have another list of id's. I want to use only the weights of the objects matching the id's in the second list.

```
d_weights = [{'d_id':'foo', 'weight': -0.7427}, ...]
d_ids = ['foo', ...]
for dtc_id in d_ids:
    d_weight = next((d['weight'] for d in d_weights if d['d_id'] == dtc_id), "")
    print str(d_weight)
    if str(d_weight) != "":
            print "not empty string! "+str(d_weight)
```

The output for this is:

```
-0.7427
0.0789
-0.0039
-0.2436
-0.0417
not empty string! -0.0417
```

Why is only the last one not empty when I can print them fine and they are obviously not equal to an empty string? How do I check that the `next()` actually returned something before using it?

Comment: Looks like it might be easier to loop using `for x in [d['weight'] for d in d_weights if d['d_id'] in ['foo', ..]]:`

Comment: @appel Kindly add the full data set for `d_weights` and `d_ids`.

Comment: I can't post the full dataset for d_weights and d_ids (way too long), I gave a representation of the dataset. How is it possible that I can print `d_weight` before the if-statement and that the comparison to an empty string does not evaluate True?

Comment: See the post, I have a list of objects with an id and a corresponding weight, and I have another list of id's. I want to use only the weights of the objects matching the id's in the second list.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on py2.7, `-0.7427` triggers the if

Comment: Well, besides the fact that you're definitely overcomplicating things (no need for `next` or generator expression), I'm pretty sure you've also left out something critical in your post. Are you sure you're giving us **all** the code, **exactly** as you have run it to get the output you've shown? You're right that the "not empty string!" message should be showing up for all the weights, not just the last one... if your code is indeed what you've posted. If you can't post all your data, fine. Just post enough to *actually* produce the output you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't correct algorithm.

So `d_weight = next((d['weight'] for d in d_weights if d['d_id'] == dtc_id), "")` iterate only once.

On every cycle `for weight_dict in d_weights:` you've got only first dict of `d_weights`.

Without more data, i can't reproduce your output.
In my case it works fine:

```
-0.7427
not empty string! -0.7427
-0.327
not empty string! -0.327
```

Correct code you can find in DhiaTN's answer.

Answer (score 0):

just iterate of the list of the keys and get the values from each dict :

```
for weight_dict in d_weights
    for key in d_ids: 
        print weight_dict.get(key, "")
```